# difference between turtle.Turtle() and x = turtle.Turtle()

Tags: python, class, variables, object, module

I had a hard time trying to frame my title since I'm still a beginner and don't know how to ask what I want to know in a concise manner.

Basically, what my question is, can someone help me figure out what the difference between just using a turtle.Turtle() function and assigning a variable to the said function is? Testing it out, using turtle.Turtle() by itself creates a new turtle object every time right. For example:

```
import turtle
turtle.Turtle().forward(90)
turtle.Turtle().left(90)
```

The above code will create two turtle objects, one that goes forward by 90 and one that turns left by 90 degrees but stays in the same spot.

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
bob.forward(90)
bob.left(90)
```

The code above will create the object Turtle and assign it to the variable bob. Then it will move that object forward by 90 and then it will turn left by 90 degrees. If bob is essentially turtle.Turtle(), why is it not creating another instance of the Turtle object every time "bob" is used?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `turtle.Turtle()` is the constructor method of the class `Turtle`; it returns an *instance* of the class. If you don't assign the output to a variable, it basically creates an instance that is *immediately* discarded (that's not entirely true, as you could still access it with the special python variable `_` right after that call.)  When you type `turtle.Turtle().forward(90)`, there's an implicit instance of the class that is created immediately "after" `turtle.Turtle()`, and the method `forward()` is called on that implicit instance. But since there's no reference to that implicit instance, it is eventually discarded by Python's garbage collector.

When you call `bob = turtle.Turtle()`, you are basically keeping a reference to the instance created (the reference is called `bob`). You can keep accessing the same instance by using the variable `bob`.

Since you don't provide the implementation of `Turtle.forward()`, we don't know what is returned by `forward()`. It could be that it doesn't return anything (i.e. returns `None`), it could return some arbitrary value **or** it could return the instance itself! In the latter case, you could do something like `bob = turtle.Turtle().forward(90)` which would essentially by the same as `bob = turtle.Turtle(); bob.forward(90)`. I'll leave it there. For a better, more complete, answer you should probably read about [OOP](Object-oriented programming) (probably is a good idea to check the references for more depth).

Comment: Ah, I think I now understand what is happening, By creating a variable bob and assigning it to the instance turtle.Turtle(), we are basically saving that instance in the variable bob. Since I'm a beginner, the way I was thinking of the = token, was more like the mathematics version of it. I try to stay clear of that way of thinking, but I guess it will come more naturally, as I keep practicing. Such a simple answer to a question that seemed so complicated! Thanks a lot for making it clear to me!

Comment: Right, that's an important distinction when you are new to a language. In Python (and many other languages) a single `=` is an assignment operator: the value on the right side is assigned to the variable on the left. Double equal signs (`==`) is the comparison operator, which returns `True` if the left and right-hand sides are equal and `False` otherwise.

Comment: Some incorrect statements in this explanation seem worth clarifying.  The underscore (_) variable only provides the result of the previous expression when Python is used interactively, not in an executed script in a file.  In standalone turtle.py, turtles that aren't assigned to a variable aren't discarded nor garbage collected, they are retained by the singular screen instance.  You can access them later using `screen.turtles()`, which doesn't seem useful but can be at times.  Finally, we do know what `forward()` returns, as it's a function provided by turtle.py -- it returns `None`.